# Find the longest single word in an array of strings

Tags: r, list, vector

In doing the seemingly classic example of manipulating the vector state.name I ran into a block trying to find what is the longest single word US State name and how long is it?

I know how to find the longest state name including spaces with the easy x[nchar(x)==max(nchar(x))], where x is the vector of names, but how to manipulate that bit of code to show that Massachusetts is the longest single word with 13 characters.

I could use a function to break apart the whole vector and use space as a delimiter, but I was hoping to keep it in the scope of the simple built in functions. Any pointers would be welcome

Comment: `strsplit` is a simple, built-in function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unlist(strsplit(x," "))[nchar(unlist(strsplit(x," ")))==max(nchar(unlist(strsplit(x," "))))]
```

Man, that's ugly... A slightly nicer way of doing it is:

```
x<-unlist(strsplit(x," "))
x[nchar(x)==max(nchar(x))]
```

Comment: you're right, very ugly, thanks a bunch, trying to figure r out for a bio project, im not one much for coding!